# Expanding animation from center of grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making an app where when it opens it expands.
But it is expanding from the side of the grid but I want it to expand from the center.
Here is the xaml code

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ExpandingAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandingGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"></EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="0"></EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="222"></EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
```

```html
<Grid x:Name="ExpandingGrid"> </Grid>
```

And this is the c# code

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Storyboard ExpandingAnime = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("ExpandingAnimation");
            ExpandingAnime.Begin();
        }
```

[Here is an example of how it looks like.](https://youtu.be/0j2maXo-yHU)

Comment: Which do you want to expand Window or Grid ("ExpandingGrid")? Could you show XAML of your Window and Grid?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the grid code
<Grid x:Name="ExpandingGrid">
</Grid>

Comment: THen how about your Window?

Comment: I have it as transparent but i don't think it makes a difference
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="442.4"
    Height="222"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    Foreground="Transparent"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

Comment: Add `VerticalAlignment="Center"` to the Grid. Your explanation "expanding from the side of the grid" doesn't match your code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `ScaleTransform` and animate its `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ExpandingAnimation">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="MyScaleTransform"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
            From="0" To ="1" Duration="0:0:3"/>
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="MyScaleTransform"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
            From="0" To ="1" Duration="0:0:3"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Storyboard>
...
<Grid x:Name="ExpandingGrid"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              Height="222">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="MyScaleTransform" ScaleX="0" ScaleY ="0" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```